# Android Async crashes when called from another class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, mobile-development, android-runonuithread

I've been trying to call an Async method from another class, but the application seems to be constantly crashing when I do so. The Async method works when I call it from within the class. I believe I've narrowed it down to when it tries to display the message on the UI thread (toast/message box). However, every solution I've tried hasn't succeeded. Below you can see my two classes. Any help will be much-appreciated thanks.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mBtLaunchActivity;
private ListView listView1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoList videoList_data[] = new VideoList[]
            {
                    //new VideoList(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy"),
                    new VideoList(R.drawable.air_squat_icon, "Air Squat Tutorial"),
                    new VideoList(R.drawable.deadlift_icon, "Deadlift Tutorial"),
                    new VideoList(R.drawable.front_squat_icon, "Front Squat Tutorial"),
                    new VideoList(R.drawable.bicep_curl_icon, "Bicep Curl Tutorial")
            };

    VideoListAdapter adapter = new VideoListAdapter(this,
            R.layout.listview_item_row, videoList_data);


    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    /*View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);*/

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    //textView userText = (textView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    //final String user = userText toString();

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position){
                case 0:

                    System.out.println("omxplayer air_squat.mp4");
                    sendCommand("ls");
                    break;

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("omxplayer deadlift.mp4");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("omxplayer front_squat.mp4");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("omxplayer bicep_curl.mp4");
                    break;
            }

            //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SSHConnectionDetails.class);
            //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //bundle.putString("vidoedetails", filedetails);
            //bundle.putString("videoname", filename);


            //intent.putExtras(bundle);
            //intent.putExtra("videofilename", filename);
            //intent.putExtra("vidoefiledetails", filedetails);
            //startActivity(intent);

            //System.out.println("Clicked pos " + position); // your code is here on item click
            //System.out.println("Clicked id " + id);
            //System.out.println(position);
        }
    });

}

private void sendCommand(String cmd){
    //String sshCommand = command;
    //SSHConnectionDetails scd = new SSHConnectionDetails();
    //scd.host = "";
    //SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    //String defaultValue = "Nothing";
    //System.out.println(getString(R.string.username));
    //String highScore = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.username), defaultValue);
    //String host = sharedPref.getString("host", "");
    //String user = sharedPref.getString("username", "");
    //String pass = sharedPref.getString("password", "");
    //int port = sharedPref.getInt("port", 22);

    //Sending over the connection details & command to be executed
    System.out.println("AT SEND COMMAND 1");
    SSHConnectionDetails scd = new SSHConnectionDetails();
    scd.sendCommand("host","user","pass",22,cmd);
    //Send host,user,pass,port,command to be executed in a method


    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), host + user + pass + port, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void launchActivity() {

    //launching the SSHConnectionDetails activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SSHConnectionDetails.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.SSH) {
        launchActivity();
        //return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

SSHConnectionDetails.java

```
public class SSHConnectionDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

private String host;
private String user;
private String pass;
private int port;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sshconnection_details);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    String host = sharedPref.getString("host", "");
    String user = sharedPref.getString("username", "");
    String pass = sharedPref.getString("password", "");
    int port = sharedPref.getInt("port", 22);

    EditText hostText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Host);
    EditText userText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.User);
    EditText passText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Pass);
    EditText portText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Port);

    hostText.setText(host, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    userText.setText(user, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    passText.setText(pass, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    portText.setText(String.valueOf(port), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),host, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void navigateUp(View view){
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
}

public void testInput2(View view){

    //Collecting the inputted connection details and assigning them to variables
    EditText userText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.User);
    user = userText.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(user);
    EditText passText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pass);
    pass = passText.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(pass);
    EditText hostText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Host);
    host = hostText.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(host);
    EditText portText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Port);
    port = Integer.parseInt(portText.getText().toString());
    System.out.println(port);

    sendCommand(host,user,pass,port,"ls");
}

public void sendCommand(final String hst, final String uname, final String pword, final int prt, final String cmd){
    System.out.println("AT SEND COMMAND 2");
    ExecuteSSHConnectionTask esct = new ExecuteSSHConnectionTask(SSHConnectionDetails.this);
    esct.execute();
}
```

}

ExecuteSSHConnectionTask.Java

```
public class ExecuteSSHConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String>{
private Context mContext;
String uname = "user";
String pword = "pass";
int prt = 22;
String hst = "host";
String cmd = "ls";

public ExecuteSSHConnectionTask(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}

ExecuteRemoteCommand erc = new ExecuteRemoteCommand(mContext);

protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    try {

        erc.executeRemoteCommand(uname, pword, hst, prt, cmd);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //displayMessage("Connection Unsuccessful: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Test";
}

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {            
        //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Test" + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //finish();

        erc.displayMessage(result);
    }
}

class ExecuteRemoteCommand{
    private Context mContext;
    public ExecuteRemoteCommand(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
public void executeRemoteCommand(
        String username,
        String password,
        String hostname,
        int port,
        String command) {
    try {
        // Setting up the session with the details provided
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
        session.setPassword(password);

        // Avoid asking for key confirmation
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop);

        session.connect();

        // SSH Channel
        ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

        // Executing the command
        //channelssh.setCommand("ls");
        channelssh.setCommand(command);
        channelssh.connect();
        channelssh.disconnect();

        // Letting the user know that a successful connection has been made to the remote computer
        //displayMessage("Connection Successful");

    } catch (JSchException e) {
        //displayMessage("Connection Unsuccessful: " + e.toString());
    }

}

    public void displayMessage(final String in){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                mContext);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        //mContext.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

**LOGCAT: https://pastebin.com/SxkNVPJ7**

Comment: Can you add logcat traces?

Comment: Sure @YogeshLakhotia https://pastebin.com/k2yW5wHX

Comment: `SSHConnectionDetails scd = new SSHConnectionDetails();` .....it´s an Activity....don´t create a new instance of an activity...I guess you have some big misunderstanding here. What are you trying to do? You should exclude the method you want to call from that activity...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I'm trying to send connection details through to the second class so that it creates an SSH connection with the details and command sent.

Comment: You can´t do it like this. Your sendCommand() method should be in an extra non activity class....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs even with adding Async into a separate Java file, the problem persists.

Comment: that maybe, I hadn´t said it´s the cause.  but it was definetely wrong. So, let´s go on and search for the issue...what is in line 121 in your `ExecuteSSHConnectionTask` class?

Comment: and again, here is also a mistake: `ExecuteRemoteCommand extends Activity` ...Why you extend an Activity here? I think you have a misunderstanding from the coding basics. In simple words, an Activity is to show a user interaction screen with all the views inside etc.. A class like your `ExecuteRemoteCommand` doesn´t need to extend an activity.

Comment: An activity is only needed to do something what you had put inside your xml layout...Textviews, buttons, layouts and so on.....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Line 121 is "AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();". I appreciate your help as I'm new to android programming. Also, I've: Removed extends Activity from ExecuteRemoteCommand class; passed mContext to ExecuteRemoteCommand and Commented out runOnUiThread this time it doesn't crash till I click off the emulator then displays the same error message.

Comment: Plus, it doesn't display the message box.

Comment: I think create is here misplaced, Your dialog has nothing, put create at the end before show(). ANyways, I recommend to create a dialog with AlertDialog.Builder. See this simple example and follow it:https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I've tried using the dialog builder that you suggested and it doesn't seem to make a difference The same error is occurring on the same line "AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                mContext);". Everytime the code reaches "erc.displayMessage(result);" and it enters displayMessage method it crashes. I don't see why this is happening.

Comment: step by step my friend. As next, you are initializing ExecuteRemoteCommand on the wrong place. At this time, mContext is null. Create the global Variable `ExecuteRemoteCommand erc=null;` and inside the constructor of `ExecuteSSHConnectionTask`, after initializing context, do: `erc = new ExecuteRemoteCommand(mContext);` . If you do it like in your code, it´s just like building a new object, but the context is null. Java/Android code is not executing in order of writing...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I've found out partially what the problem was. The MainActivity was sending commands and connection details to the sendCommand method, without the context. So, I sent over the parameter and now it doesn't crash. The other part of the problem I also resolved, I found out that doInBackground & onPostExecute don't like referring to other methods. So I put all of the code inside doInBackground & onPostExecute. The program works fine now. Thanks for your assistance anyway, much appreciated.